# JSP Scriptlets in Struts 2 Tags

Tags: google-app-engine, jsp, struts2

I have the following JSP scriptlets:

```
<input type="text" name="user.emailAddress" 
    value="<%=UserServiceFactory.getUserService().getCurrentUser().getEmail()%>" 
    readonly="readonly"/>
```

How to convert it to struts 2 tag

```
<s:textfield />
```

to avoid scriptlets.

Comment: why you want scriptlet when S2 provides a more clean way to do this and as per tag XSD it will not possible to use scriptlet.

Comment: i dont want scriptlet, what I want is to use textfield tag accessing the User service in GAE.

Comment: you can ask OGNL to do the work for you.OGNL has the power to call methods from JSP.

Comment: is it possible to access it directly in JSP page not coming from an Action?

Comment: (1) Why would you want to? Bad design. (2) S2 tags are meant to be used with an action--they call action methods to retrieve property values

Comment: i am with Dave here, use tags which will provides more clean way and still not sure why you want to skip Actions ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are opening this page, if you are using prepare method. Set this email address in that method.

```
user.setEmailAddress(UserServiceFactory.getUserService().getCurrentUser().getEmail())
```

You HTML will be

```
<s:textfield name="user.emailAddress" readonly="true" />
```